# Magento 2 Widget Only displays image

Tags: magento2, widgets

I'm trying to add a standard widget from within WYSIWYG Editor, but it does not work, because only the image is shown.

In the editor `<p>{{widget type="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Page\Link" anchor_text="bar" title="goo" template="widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="3"}}</p>`

[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?
Still no solution found..
Thanks